# How do I uninstall `php` that's not found in `yum list` or `rpm -qa`?

Tags: linux, centos, php, centos6, yum

I have a rogue php install somewhere on my server that I'd like to remove and stick with pure yum installs.

How can I find and uninstall this rogue php install?

yum and rpm searches both come up empty.

```
$ yum list installed | grep -i php
$ rpm -qa | grep -i php
$ php -v
-bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

And yet the browser can return a simple `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` page.

Comment: Is it so hard to check web server configuration to find out what is it doing when a request for php file is done? Check all writable directories by www or www-data user (/var/tmp, /tmp, /home ...??).

Answer (score 1):

It may be that only the apache php module was installed and not the commandline interpreter. You disable the module by not loading it in your httpd.conf (or the config includes).

The alternative to installing from package is either copying binaries or compiling from source.

With a bit of luck the sources remain and you could try if the Makefile file has an uninstall section and `make uninstall` works.

If not then simply deleting by hand is the only way to remove the software. The makefile may contain some hints on where components were installed.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$ find / -name php -type f -executable 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/php
```

(might need to get some coffee while it runs).

Answer (score 0):

There is all package I have installed on server:

```
rpm -aq | grep php
php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
php-pdo-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
```

There are all instaled files in system. Try to find.

See in  /etc/httpd/modules

> libphp5.so

rpm -ql php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64

```
/etc/php.d
/etc/php.d/curl.ini
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini
/etc/php.d/json.ini
/etc/php.d/phar.ini
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
/etc/php.ini
/usr/lib64/php
/usr/lib64/php/modules
/usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/phar.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so
/usr/lib64/php/pear
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/CODING_STANDARDS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/CREDITS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/EXTENSIONS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/INSTALL
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.EXTENSIONS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.EXT_SKEL
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.MAILINGLIST_RULES
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.PARAMETER_PARSING_API
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.PHP4-TO-PHP5-THIN-CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.REDIST.BINS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.RELEASE_PROCESS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.SELF-CONTAINED-EXTENSIONS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.STREAMS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.SUBMITTING_PATCH
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.SVN-RULES
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.TESTING
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.TESTING2
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.UNIX-BUILD-SYSTEM
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.WIN32-BUILD-SYSTEM
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.input_filter
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.namespaces
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/TSRM_LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/ZEND_CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/ZEND_LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/php.ini-development
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/php.ini-production
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/regex_COPYRIGHT
/usr/share/php
/var/lib/php
```

rpm -ql php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64

```
/etc/php.d
/etc/php.d/curl.ini
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini
/etc/php.d/json.ini
/etc/php.d/phar.ini
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
/etc/php.ini
/usr/lib64/php
/usr/lib64/php/modules
/usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/phar.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so
/usr/lib64/php/pear
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/CODING_STANDARDS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/CREDITS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/EXTENSIONS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/INSTALL
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.EXTENSIONS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.EXT_SKEL
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.MAILINGLIST_RULES
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.PARAMETER_PARSING_API
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.PHP4-TO-PHP5-THIN-CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.REDIST.BINS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.RELEASE_PROCESS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.SELF-CONTAINED-EXTENSIONS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.STREAMS
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.SUBMITTING_PATCH
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.SVN-RULES
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.TESTING
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.TESTING2
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.UNIX-BUILD-SYSTEM
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.WIN32-BUILD-SYSTEM
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.input_filter
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/README.namespaces
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/TSRM_LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/ZEND_CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/ZEND_LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/php.ini-development
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/php.ini-production
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/regex_COPYRIGHT
/usr/share/php
/var/lib/php
```

rpm -ql php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
/var/lib/php/session
/var/www/icons/php.gif
```